# Highcharts - Cannot display data labels on a spline chart

Tags: highcharts

I am trying all kinds of permutations to make data labels on the spline chart but I just dont know what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/V9LML/)

```
             plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
    name: 'Value',
            data: [

    [Date.UTC(2005,9,01), 2.02],[Date.UTC(2006,8,30), 7.56],[Date.UTC(2007,8,29), 5.22],[Date.UTC(2008,8,27), 6.57],[Date.UTC(2009,9,03), -4.48],[Date.UTC(2010,9,02), 5.29],[Date.UTC(2011,9,01), 7.44],[Date.UTC(2012,8,29), 3.39],[Date.UTC(2013,8,28), 6.54],
            ]
        }]
```

Comment: what do you mean data labels?

Comment: Check the fiddle in the answer given below, the labels are the numbers which display just above the points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under `plotOptions`, you are setting the `dataLabels` option for `line` charts, not `spline` charts.  They have to match:

```
        plotOptions: {
            spline: { // has to say spline here
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9LML/1/).

Comment: I have wasted a lot of time on this, didn't think it would be so silly. Thanks Mark.